# Eclipse jsp-files formatting

Tags: java, jsp

Is this a good way of formatting for JSP files? How can I change it? I don't like it.

```
<%@ page
        language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta
        http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

        <form
                name="loginForm"
                method="POST"
                action="controller">
                <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="command"
                        value="login" /> Login:<br /> <input
                        type="text"
                        name="login"
                        value=""><br /> Password:<br /> <input
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value=""> <br /> <input
                        type="submit"
                        value="Enter">
        </form>
        <hr />



</body>
</html>
```

`Web > JSP files > Editor` didn't help me

Any advices?

EDIT:

How can I change default format of jsp files(default format of jsp files is shown above)?

Comment: Nothing related to programming in this question.

Comment: Can you plz clarify your question ? Not able to understand atall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you've to just go to `Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor` and uncheck the option "Split multiple attributes each on a new line".

[image]